# WordPress Customizer checkbox default not working

Tags: theme-customizer

I am having a problem with the WordPress Customizer checkbox default value.

No matter what I put in the default value, but the checkbox is always checked in the theme customizer.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'swastika_social_youtube', array(
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'default'    =>  'false',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'swastika_sanitize_checkbox',
    ) 
);

$wp_customize->add_control( 'swastika_social_youtube', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'section' => 'social_settings_section', 
    'label'      => __( 'Show Youtube Icon', 'swastika' ),
    ) 
);
```

And here is how I am showing icon

```
<?php if ( true == get_theme_mod( 'swastika_social_youtube', false ) ) { ?> 
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

[image]

Please Help Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default of `'false'` is actually a string, which evaluates to true because it's not empty.
Use plain `false`, without the quotes.